# How to implement ForeignKey search in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When developing the API, I tried to implement a search system but encountered an error

```
Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted.
```

Models

```
class GroupTask(models.Model):
    UserToken = models.TextField(default="")
    NameGroupTask = models.TextField(null=True)
    StatusGroupTask= models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['NameGroupTask']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NameGroupTask[0:50]


class TaskForGroup(models.Model):
    UserToken = models.TextField(default="")
    NameTaskForGroup= models.TextField(null=True)
    DescriptionTask = models.TextField(null=True)
    StatusTaskForGroup= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Group = models.ForeignKey(GroupTask, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['NameTaskForGroup']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.NameTaskForGroup[0:50]
```

viewsets for output

```
class TaskForGroupAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # показываем что доступны все методы для работы с данными (post, get, put, delete запросы)
    queryset= TaskForGroup.objects.all()
    # указываем сериализатор
    serializer_class = TaskForGroupSerializer 
    # устанавливаем классы для фильтрации 
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    # указываем поле по которому проводить фильтрацию 
    search_fields = ['Group',]

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
       return Response(data)
```

how am I trying to find the TaskForGroup I need

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/TaskForGroupAPI/TaskForGroupAPI/?search=5
```

Comment: Side note: You should read up on python naming conventions - it's very confusing reading your code when variables are named like classes. https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the fields `search_fields` using spanning-relationship

```py
class TaskForGroupAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # Existing code
    search_fields = [
        'Group__UserToken',
        "Group__NameGroupTask",
        "Group__StatusGroupTask"
    ]
```